# Drawing arc between two points using Java?

Tags: java

I have two points (x1y1 and x2y2), the centre point between the two lines (x0y0), and I am trying to draw an arc using the following Java method:

```
g.fillArc(x of initial point, y of initial point, width of arc, height of arc, start angle, end angle)
```

to get this:

[image]

I have found radius:

```
int r = (int)Math.sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)*(y1-y0));
```

then width and height:

```
int width = 2*r;
int height = 2*r;
```

and then start and end angles:

```
int startAngle1 = (int) (180/Math.PI*Math.atan2(y1-y0, x1-x0));
int endAngle1 = (int) (180/Math.PI*Math.atan2(y2-y0, x2-x0));
```

Instead, I get this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Trying to figure out the proper way to draw the arc.

EDIT:

These are geographical coordinates as well as x and y coordinates on the screen based on the zoom property:

Point 1:

```
X1 coordinates: [25.7745, -81.4589]
X1 and Y1: 574043 : 893092
X2 coordinates: [25.82111, -81.45741]
X2 and Y2: 574052 : 892790
X0 coordinates: [25.797805001897803, -81.45815514647514]
X0 and Y0: 574047 : 892941
```

Point 2:

```
X1 coordinates: [26.85249, -80.8777]
X1 and Y1: 577429 : 886086
X2 coordinates: [26.87219, -80.8392]
X2 and Y2: 577653 : 885957
X0 coordinates: [26.862341303504717, -80.8584516762013]
X0 and Y0: 577541 : 886022
```

Comment: please add the example coordinates, radii etc to the questions

Comment: This isn't a GIS question as much a a "How to use the Java graphics API" issue. You might have had a faster response over in [so] proper.

Comment: Ian. I have edited my question to include coordinates. Thank you.

Comment: Vince. I believe I have a problem with finding proper start and end angles or centre coordinates. There are no issues with the Java API. Thank you.